# Django send mail from smtp.office365.com

Tags: django, email, django-settings, office365connectors

system support messages has to go from smtp.office365.com mail account.

settings are:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'outlook-nameast4.office365.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*********'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

hosts like: smtp.office365.com etc (this was the initial one), and other obtained with

```
dig smtp.office365.com
```

were tested so as the PORT 25:

I don't receive any error notifications, but messages are not received.
Whole system works perfect with gmail settings.

Note: I tried both dynamic and static IPs

Answer (score 2):

The solution was simple.Microsoft is strict on * from field - it has to be the same as sender's mail address, no any "Notification system" etc. What works for google - not the same for Microsoft. IF go strictly to django documentation - this problem will not appear.

Comment: I want to add that it is also possible to use shared mailbox address.